# TC358743XBG HDMI to CSI-2 Board

Tags: raspberry-pi, video, hdmi

I've got a project in which I have video output from a camera which I can have in either video out or HDMI out. This signal, then, is to be sent to a Raspberry Pi to be used in a computer vision application. The Raspberry Pi can process video through MIPI/CSI-2 or through USB as a standard webcam. I have looked at HDMI to MIPI/CSI-2 conversion boards, and they can run pretty expensive. I think this is because of low demand. At the core of these conversion boards is a TC358743XBG chip from Toshiba.

My question is

a) How feasible is it for me (I have soldering experience) to make my own conversion board (purely from a hardware perspective- I'll worry about drivers later)?

[Would it be possible to adapt this project to suit my needs?](http://hackaday.io/project/364-mipi-dsi-display-shieldhdmi-adapter)

b) Might there be a better way?

Comment: Not to judge your level of skill, but *"I'll worry about drivers later"* are famous last words. It took a year of part time work, for several broadcom employees who work on this stuff in the day, to get the camera drivers into great shape. Read the raspistill threads on the Pi forums to get an idea of the scale of the task. The hardware connection seems easy by comparison. If you're not a driver/gpu/broadcom expert, consider a USB frame grabber?

Comment: @tomnexus, point taken. However, I seem to recall "6by9", a member on the RasPi forums mentioning that there were working prototypes floating around the Foundation offices. Incidentally, he's a former Broadcom employee. Anyhow, my assumption is that if I do get hardware working that I can beg for the driver they use and adapt it for my purposes. My main concern is the construction of the converter as the 3 I found online are all over $200 USD. Not sure why this is considering the Toshiba chip they use is ~$8 USD.

Comment: @tomnexus, any chance you can direct me to a resource or explain how I can make an HDMI UVC capture card?

Comment: They seem to be for sale. Again I don't think you'll save money making one. Only worthwhile developing it if you sell thousands. Component MOQs could even make your first one cost more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TC358743 comes with BGA package. So hand soldering will not be possible. This can only be assembled with Re-flow process.